# Coupon wrong Grand Total Caclulation and minimum order value... again

Tags: magento-1.7, tax, coupon

1. I've read a lot about this problem, but mine seems to be ... different. I have 1 item in my cart and I've used a discount cupon - look at the result.

   [image: Screenshot Cart]

   Somehow 0,50 € are being added to the VAT.... from nowhere!!! If I add 2 items, then instead of 0,50€, 1,01€ is being added. Does
   anyone know about this bug? 
   This only seems to happen if I use the discount coupon
2. I have a rule "min. order value = 20€". If I use the discount coupon I can't go to checkout because " The min. order value is not reached...". So it seems that magento is looking at the Grand Total Value and not at the Order value. I could go ahead and change it in the **/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php** file. But is this really a bug of magento?

Comment: For point #1, have you set the coupon to discount a fixed % (100%) or a fixed amount (27.80EUR)?

Comment: fixed amount of 100EUR

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to rewrite your rules.

**Rule #1**

Discount cart to 0.00 if order amount is less than 100.00EUR. For this rule, set the CONDITIONS as follows:

```
If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :
    Subtotal equals or less than  100.00
```

And the ACTIONS:

```
Apply: Percent of product price discount.
Discount amount*: 100
```

That should sort out the first rule. Now the 20EUR one.

**Rule #2**

You need to ensure that the following are set in the ACTIONS:

```
Apply to Shipping Amount: No
Stop Further Rules Processing: No
```

You could possibly combine these rules into one using the CONDITIONS section on the ACTIONS tab, something like:

```
If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :
    Price in cart greater than 20.00
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi - 1. This didn't help :( But to solve this issue i had to change the "Tax Calculation Method Based On" in the Main Tax Settings. 2. I have no actions at all. The min order value is in the Main Settings (Confgi->Sales->min Order amout)

Comment: Oh I see, I got the wrong end of the stick entirely. Still think Rule 1 will work, no?

Comment: I think it would work, if I would use internal actions in rules.